# emacs, How to copy region, and leave it highlighted?

Tags: emacs

I'm happy enough with the default M-w as `(kill-ring-save)` which loses the region's highlighting upon running the command. I don't want to alter its behaviour, but I do want to re-bind `<C-insert>` to perform a similar action and maintain the region's highlighting.

I've tried (un)setting `transient-mark-mode` directly and via a function, but the region still loses its highlighting.

Running only `(kill-ring-save (region-beginning) (region-end))` in an interactive function works as expected, ie. it loses highlighting.

Running only `(exchange-point-and-mark) (exchange-point-and-mark)` in an interactive function works as expected, ie. it re-highlights the region and puts/leaves point in its original/correct place.

However when I put them all together in a function, it does *not* re-highlight the region. Here is non-functioning function and binding:

```
(defun kill-ring-save-keep-highlight ()
  (interactive)
  (kill-ring-save (region-beginning) (region-end))
  (exchange-point-and-mark) (exchange-point-and-mark)
)
(global-unset-key (kbd "<C-insert>"))
(global-set-key   (kbd "<C-insert>") 'kill-ring-save-keep-highlight)
```

---

Using: GNU Emacs  23.1.1  in Ubuntu 10.04.3

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Running `kill-ring-save` doesn't deactivate the mark directly, but merely sets the variable `deactivate-mark` to `t` in order for the deactivation to be done *afterward*. To prevent this, reset `deactivate-mark` to `nil` *before* the deactivation.

```
(defun kill-ring-save-keep-highlight (beg end)
  "Keep the region active after the kill"
  (interactive "r")
  (prog1 (kill-ring-save beg end)
    (setq deactivate-mark nil)))

(global-set-key (kbd "<C-insert>") 'kill-ring-save-keep-highlight)
```

Answer (score 0):

The region is highlighted because the mark is "active" - so expressly activating the mark does the trick.  Note: I'm not quite sure why exchanging the point/mark doesn't work.  Here's an updated function, I also updated it to use interactive to fill in the arguments.

```
(defun kill-ring-save-keep-highlight (beg end)
  "Keep the region active after the kill"
  (interactive "r")
  (kill-ring-save beg end)
  (activate-mark))
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointers on interactive args and `activate-mark`, but it still doesn't work. I even installed a clean-slate VM of Ubuntu 11.04 with the only code in `.emacs` being this function, but it still doesn't activate the mark, yet manually applying `C-x C-x` immediately after `C-insert` does reinstate the highlighting...

Comment: @fred have you tried it in an Emacs w/out your .emacs?  i.e. run `emacs -q` with the code and check to see if it works.

Comment: I had run it (unsuccesfully) without anything *except* this one function in `~/.emacs` and without anything in `~/.emacs.d/`, and as mentioned, also in a brand-new install of emacs in a brand new VM....  I've now tried this command, but it too doesn't work: `/usr/bin/emacs --no-init-file --no-site-file --eval '(defun kill-ring-save-keep-highlight (beg end)  (interactive "r")  (kill-ring-save beg end)  (activate-mark))'` ... Does the function work foryou?